# Custom Animation Class

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

For my application, I am trying to implement a character who displays a walking animation when walking and displays a jumping animation when in the air.

Using Cocos2D, I've created a simple animation. The problem is that the I am using CCRepeatForever and I cannot seem to stop the animation or switch it once I set it off.

Steffen Itterheim's book discussed some animation in the chapter regarding sprites. The way he created an animation was to add multiple sprite frames to a CCAnimation object and then run it with CCRepeatForever.

I'm currently looking at two possiblities:
1) Create multiple sprites and add them to a CCArray and then loop through the multiple sprites.
2) Find an alternate solution to CCRepeatForever and find a way to stop the animation or switch to a different animation.

The problem with number 1 is that I cannot figure out a way to render a selective sprite to the stage. It seems to be that the only way to add a sprite to the screen is to use [self addChild:mySprite]; This is limiting and problematic if I want to switch between multiple sprites. Is there a way to selectively render a sprite?
The problem for number 2 is that there seems to be no alternate to CCRepeatForever and the other animation classes are not sufficient for running the animation.

Thank you!

Comment: You can stop it, you need to give it a tag/name or something, I just can't remember what at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you assign a tag to the action like the following.

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image.png"];
CCRotateBy *spinAction = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1 angle:90];
CCRepeatForever *spinForever = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:spinAction];
[spinForever setTag:ANIMATION_TAG];
[sprite runAction:spinForever];
```

you can stop the animation by calling

```
[sprite stopActionByTag:ANIMATION_TAG];
```

Comment: Also, you can use

- (void) stopAction:  (CCAction *)  action 
Removes an action from the running action list

or 

- (void) stopAllActions   
Removes all actions from the running action list

Comment: One day this answer will be accepted. I have a dream.